# How do I get a list of all valid screen resolutions in Python?

Tags: python, screen, resolution

I need to get a list of all valid screen resolutions of the users display in Python. I would prefer it if this could be done without any external modules. Is this at all possible? I only need this to work on Windows.

Comment: There are lots of screen resolutions, and im not sure If you can get it throug the os....you can do it manually in a function but it will not be fully coplete...

Comment: Lack informations about your OS

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you can do it using `ctypes`, part of the standard library:

```
import ctypes
sdl_dll = ctypes.CDLL("sdl.dll")
modes = sdl_dll.SDL_ListModes(None, None)
```

However, you will have to parse the returned objects (there is more information on this [here](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?281469-Get-supported-display-resolutions)).

Alternatively, you could try [`pygame`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.list_modes)'s `display.list_modes()`, which gives a "friendlier" return and will work cross-platform but requires installation.

Comment: You are assuming that OP are using `windows`, it's not specified anywhere